# How to avoid multiple levels of nested functions

Tags: python

I'm working with the python code that has 4 levels of nested functions. You can see an example below:

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def calculate(self, x, y):
        results = []

        result = None
        context = API.send_request('get_context')
        if context['result'] == 'ok':
            result = context['data']
        # Some more actions here

        def _is_valid_variable(variable):
            if (variable > 0 and
                variable % 2 == 0 and
                variable < 10):
                return True

            return False

        def _format_data(data):
            formatted_data = None

            def _extract_time(line):
                time = None

                if line:
                    time = line.split('|')[-1]

                return time

            if data:
                for line in data.split('\n'):
                    formatted_data += '[DEBUG] [{0}] {1}'.format(_extract_time(line), line.split('|')[1])

            return formatted_data


        return results
```

In this example there are only 3 levels but idea is the same.

What's the better way of structuring such type of code?

Is it better to put all closures/inner functions at the beginning of the parent function not to mix the with the code?

P.S. I wouldn't like to put these functions out to the level of class as far as they are not actually related to the class but only to theirs' parent function.

Comment: [*"Flat is better than nested."*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) Your nested functions don't appear to need the closure, so don't need to be nested at all.

Comment: ^-- +1, I couldn't see any reason you need "nested" functions, simple class methods or staticmethod will do just fine. Don't over complicate your code.

Comment: If the functions are defined inside a function, then they are _redefined each time the function runs_. That makes your function slower for no good reason.

Comment: @Anzel, the only reason was that these inner functions are not actually connected to class but only to parent functions. It means that they are needed only by particular function but not whole class.

Comment: @WhiteAngel, that's what `staticmethods` are here for. Or you can even write normal functions to call upon. That still doesn't explain why you need to "nest" them inside your method, it only hurts readability with no real gained benefits

Comment: your functions are only related to the parent function, and named according to that context (`_is_valid_variable`, the notion of `valid` is defined for that context.) If you flatten your hierarchy, you should give those functions more generally descriptive names (`_is_pair_in_bounds`, for example, adding the 0 and 10 as parameters). Likewise, `_extract_time` could be named `_last_column`, possibly the `|` could be a parameter. (with a default value)

Answer (score 2):

These are plain function that depend neither on your class or instance nor of the calling function's context, so just put them at the module's top level.